# Advanced SQL Data Compare throught multiple tables

Tags: sql, synchronization, comparison

Consider the situation below.
Two tables (A & B), in two environments (DEV & TEST), with records in those tables.
If you look the content of the tables, you understand that functionnal data are identical.
I mean except the PK and FK values, the name Roger is sill connected to Fruit & Vegetable.

### In DEV environment :

**Table A**
1 Roger
2 Kevin

**Table B** (italic field is FK to table A)
1 *1* Fruit
2 *1* Vegetable
3 *2* Meat

### In TEST environment :

**Table A**
4 Roger
5 Kevin

**Table B** (italic field is FK to table A)
7 *4* Fruit
8 *4* Vegetable
9 *5* Meat

I'm looking for a SQL Data Compare tool which will tell me there is no difference in the above case.
Or if there is, it will generate insert & update scripts with the right order (insert first in A then B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on Red Gate : http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=8401#top

I contacted them and they told me this feature will be implemented in the next version of Data Compare.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try [dbForge Data Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/) from Devart. It allows you to compare data and set that consequence of actions that you need. Check out it's perfomance and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) as part of the [SQL Toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Professional_Toolbelt/index.htm) from [Red Gate Software](http://www.red-gate.com/)

I'm *VERY* happy with it's performance and functionality.

Comment: He would need the data compare tool actually. SQL Compare compares schema's. I believe both tools come in the toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

Most data compare tools allow you to ignore columns; however, you want them to not ignore the FK columns but determine that Test.TableA's 4 is equal to Dev.TableA's 1 so that the first row in Table B is the same. Is this correct?

I don't know of any tool that can do this. Now for your second question, most of the data compare tools will generate scripts in the correct order for you. You can look into Redgate's [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm).

If you have Visual Studio Developer Edition it comes with a Data Compare tool (Available as separate install called Visual Studio Database Edition)

Comment: Well at a minimum you can find tools which can make the data the same.

Comment: I seen this topic on RedGate : http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=8401#top

Comment: Heh can you enable on update cascade on your FK's? Also contact them and see if they fixed the bug: SDC-889. You can also disable the FK's do the update then reenable them.

Comment: I contact them, the bug/functionallity will be available in june 09 -lucky-)

Comment: Sweet I +1 your question for doing the leg work to my answer;-) Hope it works, out. Redgate has really good tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stored proc which compares any two tables.  It turns out that this also works on views.  So I can compare two views which each return a "flattened" version of a schema.  I can either leave out columns like identity/surrogate keys or instruct my proc to ignore them.

As far as inserting, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Finding any discrepancies is straightforward with [SqlDiffFramework](https://github.com/msorens/SqlDiffFramework), a visual diff program for data sources (rather than *files* like your typical diff program). As the name implies, it is a framework: you have to feed it two queries to compare, one for your DEV environment and one for your TEST environment. In your particular case, the queries will be identical, something like:

```
SELECT A.person, B.foodgroup
FROM A JOIN B on A.IdPerson = B.IdPerson
ORDER BY A.person, B.foodgroup
```

SqlDiffFramework provides two side-by-side query tools in one window. You simply point one side to your DEV database and the other to your TEST database, then run both queries to fetch and compare the data. (You can even save snapshots and then run a diff on the snapshots of your choice to see how differences, if any, emerge over time.)

Note, however, that SqlDiffFramework does *not* address the second part of your request, to generate scripts to make them match.

[SqlDiffFramework, version 1.0, introduced 2010.04.29, is open-source and freely available.]

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Data Examiner](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Data_Examiner/). I like this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2008 you can use a merge statement and it will insert update or delete based on what you want to do.